# how target two facets name str_replace?

Tags: php

How to say price and surface should change their button text 'go' to 'search'

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_facet_html', function( $output, $params ) {
        if ( 'price','surface' == $params['facet']['name'] ) {
            $output = str_replace( 'Go', 'Search', $output );
        }
        return $output;
    }, 10, 2 );
```

`if ( 'price','surface' ==` does not seem to work.. I think it is not like that it should be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array` instead of comma separated values:

```
if( in_array($params['facet']['name'], ['price','surface']) {
    ...
}
```